# Django is not rendering ListView

Tags: django, listview, templates

I had another post related to this but my code was complex so the communication was difficult. I completely stripped off the issue from the unnecessary details and came up with a very minimal example shown below:

*templates/base.html:*

```
<html>
  <body>
  <p>I am base.html</p>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock content %}
  </body>
</html>
```

*templates/blog.html:*

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <p>I am blog.html</p>

    {{ blog_list }}
    {% for blog in blog_list %}
    {{ blog.title }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

And *blog/views.py*

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Blog


class BlogList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Blog.objects.filter()
    template_name = 'blog.html'
    # context_object_name = 'blog_list'


class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog.html'
```

That outputs this:
[image]

I was expecting the list of blog titles to be rendered there. I debugged the BlogList class and queryset value was this:

```
<QuerySet [<Blog: First Page>, <Blog: Intro>]>
```

So, the query is not empty. I have been completely frustrated by this issue. Anyone know what's going on?

Edit: Here is *blog/urls.py*:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:parent>/<slug:slug>/', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name='blog'),
]
```

And project *urls.py*:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('qa.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Comment: I see `BlogDetail` also uses `blog.html`? Please add your url patterns to the question.

Comment: Have you tried un commenting `context_object_name`?

Comment: @Mugoma, yes. Nothing changed.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ok. Please see the edits.

Comment: @multigoodverse and where is the url pattern that points to `BlogList`?...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat  I added `path('<str:parent>/<slug:slug>/', views.BlogList.as_view(), name='blog_list')` to url_patterns of blog/urls.py but nothing changed. What exactly should I add in url_patterns?

Comment: How is the pattern `'<str:parent>/<slug:slug>/'` any different from the one for `BlogDetail`? Django simply uses the _first_ matching pattern for any url.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat got it. Then, the solution is to remove the first URL and only leave the second. Am I right?

Comment: What I am trying to say that leaving BlogList and removing BlodDetails from the URL patterns will sacrifice BlogDetails for BlogList. Any way to keep both?

Answer (score 0):

After some clues given by @Abdul Aziz Barkat, I realized the problem is I should be linking to the BlogDetail view instead of BlogList view. So, I changed urlpatterns of blog/urls.py to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:parent>/<slug:slug>/', views.BlogDetail.as_view(), name='blog_list'),
]
```

The problem now is BlogList is not being rendered anymore, but we don't need BlogList anymore - we can create a queryset inside BlogDetail and provide the queryset as a context. To achieve that I added a queryset variable and a get_context_data method to BlogDetail:

```
class BlogDetail(generic.DetailView):

    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blog.html'
    queryset = Blog.objects.filter()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['blog_list'] = self.queryset
        return context
```